# Getting maximum resolution via mini display in Macbook Pro

Tags: display, multiple-monitors, hdmi, macbook

I have a Macbook Pro(2014) and right now I bought an Asus monitor(ASUS VN289H) but I think there is a problem with resolution. I was expected a large display with lots of space but right now I have a big display but user interface is big too. I use HDMI cable and when I use Mini display to VGA cable, I get the same resolution and there is no difference.

I have another option, buying a Mini Display to HDMI cable. What i want to know is that this configuration can be better? or HDMI cable is the best?

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid that Asus is only an "HD" screen, 1920x1080 (1080p), so it's gonna have some pretty big pixels to fill a 28" screen.
If your Mac has a retina screen you're gonna find the Asus hugely disappointing.

You really want a 1440p screen (2560x1440) or better to give you what you are wanting to see.

Have a look at [EveryMac](http://www.everymac.com/systems/apple/macbook_pro/index-macbookpro.html) to see exactly what screen sizes are supported by your particular machine. There are too many versions of the 2014 MBP to generalise.